# Losing my mind - VBA function in excell cell, unexplained #ref

Tags: excel, vba, function, ref

It's not that I don't know WHAT exactly is going wrong but it's the not knowing WHY it's going wrong thats making me lose my mind.

When writing any function in VBA with a name that has less than 4 characters and ends with a number, eq:

`public function fun1(variable)`
or
`public function fn1(variable)`

And then using that function in an excell cell will always give a #ref error.[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDCwf.png)

In the example a simple function for changing casing.

Is there someone who could relieve me from this dark place i'm currently in of not knowing what is going wrong.

Comment: Please set the title  of your question to something meaningfull. "Losing my mind" isn't a useful description of the problem. Always keep in mind that someone with a similar problem could find an answer on SO without raising a new question

Comment: Your function name can be interpreted as a valid cell reference on the excel worksheet.  Hence your error.  Note that this will also occur with valid cell references in either A1 or R1C1 notation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the names are ambiguous, `fun1` and `fn1` are both valid Range names.
Change the name to something like `MyFunction` and it will work.